# im trying to create a join role function and it doesn't work

Tags: discord.py, python-3.10

so it basically goes like this:
I'm trying to create a function that can add a member from a specific role and also the function will see that if the member is in that role or if that is role is exist and if the max members of this role is five but the code doesn't seem to work

```py
    @commands.command()
    async def join_team(self,ctx,rule:discord.Role):
        role = ctx.guild.get_role(rule) # check this specific role
        if ctx.author in role:
            await ctx.send("you're already in that role !")
        elif len(role.members) == 5:
            await ctx.send("this specific role is full")
        else:
            await self.client.add_roles(ctx.author, role)
```

**The error I get:**

```py
Ignoring exception in command join_team:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\PYTHON\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\Name\Desktop\scripts\python's\discordbot\cogs\cog1.py", line 29, in join_team
    if ctx.author in role:
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\PYTHON\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "E:\PYTHON\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "E:\PYTHON\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

Comment: What does not seem to work? Any errors?

Answer (score 1):

You just have a logic error in your code.

What you are checking if the `author` is `in` the `role` which does not make any sense here.

Check it the other way around instead:

```py
if role in ctx.author.roles: 
 # Do what you want to do
```

Comment: And how can I check the amount of members in the “certain role” I entered ?

Comment: @Dachillprogrammer If you mean how many members that has that role, you can access that with [`Role.members`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Role.members) which returns you a list of [`Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member) objects. I suggest you use `len()` to get the amount on it

Comment: @Dachillprogrammer This was not part of the question/is not shown in the error. Is this not working too?

Comment: Well…yes and your solution didn’t work I mean the role.member

Comment: @Dachillprogrammer Kindly read the docs and think of logic before writing the code.

Answer (score 0):

You're logic and the code both are wrong.
You're already getting role on parameter but still pass it to [`get_role()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#discord.Guild.get_role) and you're also checking if the author is in a role object not members with the role.
Bot object does not have [`add_roles()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#discord.Member.add_roles) function.

```py
    @commands.command()
    async def join_team(self, ctx, role: discord.Role):

        if role in ctx.author.roles:
            await ctx.send("you're already in that role !")

        elif len(role.members) == 5:
            await ctx.send("this specific role is full")

        else:
            await ctx.author.add_roles(role)
```